# Read cell in each row of datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently developing an application in C# where I need to read the values of the cell of each row in a DataGridView in C#.

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tblCategories.Rows)
        {
            string folderPath = tblBackups.Rows[row].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            string backupIncludes = tblBackups.Rows[row].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Folder Path: " + folderPath);
            Console.WriteLine("Backup Includes: " + backupIncludes);
        }
```

For some reason, this is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find out the problem for myself.

I changed the code to the following:

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tblCategories.Rows)
        {
            string folderPath = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            string backupIncludes = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Folder Path: " + folderPath);
            Console.WriteLine("Backup Includes: " + backupIncludes);
        }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: That's what I wrote... seemed off that you were getting the row and then getting it again from the collection

Comment: You might want to use the columns that you've designed instead of hardcoding the index. If the user is allowed to change the order of the columns you might not  get the values that you're expecting in there.